# .htacces - how to block server for everyone with a custom message?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, block

Is it possible to block a server by:

```
deny from all
```

(or by other way in the .htaccess file) and display some message like

```
For technical reasons the server is temporarily unavailable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [redirect to a maintenance page](http://wiki.lunarpages.com/Redirect_to_Maintenance_Page_Using_htaccess).